# Getting an error when trying to import matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, ipython

I am using `ipython` when I am trying to `import matplotlib`.

I am getting following error

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/akajappan/<ipython-input-4-82be63b7783c> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib

/home/akajappan/matplotlib.py in <module>()
----> 1 from pylab import plotfile, show, gca
      2 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
      3 
      4 fname = cbook.get_sample_data('msft.csv', asfileobj=False)
      5 fname2 = cbook.get_sample_data('data_x_x2_x3.csv', asfileobj=False)

ImportError: No module named pylab
```

I tried to install `scipy` still the error exists. 
(`sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib`)

Operating system : `ubuntu 12.04`

Comment: It seems you are not really importing matplotlib but a script you named matplotlib.py in the same folder.

Comment: @joaquin this is also possible. I checked the directory

Comment: never name a script like an existing library. rule of thumb

Comment: @joaquin Actually there is no file called matplotlib.py

Comment: your traceback says the contrary: /home/akajappan/matplotlib.py

Comment: @joaquin Yeah, reason for confusion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60504/discussion-between-joaquin-and-karu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are satisfied with workaround - install anaconda distribution. This is a python distribution with all (or most) scientific packages installed. It saved me, it may help you as well.

http://continuum.io/downloads

Comment: What about previous packages ?

Comment: fedosov$ which python > /Users/fedosov/anaconda/bin/python. 
I set it as a default interpreter. Saved me a lot of pain in installing and troubleshooting packages. I had problems with scypi on mac and anaconda solved it.

Comment: Ok, How to use it? like normal python. Can I use it with ipython note book?

Comment: Just like normal python/ipython. Use python/ipython from /path_to_anaconda/anaconda/bin/

Comment: I have a mac on which I've just installed Python 3.5, followed by Pycharm, and finally the Anaconda distribution.  When I open IDLE for Python 3.5, and type in "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt", I get the error **No module named: matplotlib**.  Do you have any idea on how I can fix this?  I'm a beginner with python and have been struggling for hours with this.

Comment: Just a follow up to my last comment: I don't know how to make PyCharm choose the anaconda distribution automatically for each new project, but when creating a new project, it will ask for the location and the interpreter.  Under interpreter, choose the selection with the word "anaconda" in it.  Also, if a project has already been created, on a Mac you can open the project, and then open preferences, and go to **Build, Execution, Deployment** >> **Console** >> **Python Console** and choose the anaconda selection in "Python Interpreter".